# Moving an item with the mouse on QGraphicsView / QGraphicsScene

Tags: c++, qt, graphics, mouse

I have a `QGraphicsView` area that displays some Item items. I would like to have mouse move implemented.

```
class Item
{
public:
    Item();
    void update();
    int x, y; // position
    int z; // order - should correspond also to index in item list
};

class Collection : public QGraphicsView
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    Collection(QWidget *parent = 0);
    void update();
    QList<Item> *m_items;
protected:
    virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent * event);
    virtual void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent * event);
    virtual void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
private:
    QPoint offset;
    int itemMoved;
};
```

trying:

```
void Collection::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
    Item *currentItem = NULL;
    itemMoved = -1;
    foreach (QGraphicsItem *item, this->items(event->pos()))
    {

// never get into this loop since my items are not children of QGraphicsItem

        currentItem = dynamic_cast<Item*>(item);
        if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton && currentItem)
        {
            itemMoved = currentItem->z;
            offset = event->pos();
        }
        else if (event->button() == Qt::RightButton)
        {
            // set right click stuff
        }
        else
        {
            event->ignore();
        }
        break;
    }
}

void CollectionView::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
    if(event->button() == Qt::LeftButton && itemMoved > 0)
    {
        m_items->at(itemMoved).x = event->pos().x();
        m_items->at(itemMoved).y = event->pos().y();

// So far multiple fails:

//    error: assignment of data-member 'Item::x' in read-only structure
//    error: assignment of data-member 'Item::y' in read-only structure
//    error: passing 'const Item' as 'this' argument of 'void Item::update()' discards qualifiers

        m_items->at(itemMoved).update();
        update();
    }
}
```

I would make my `Item` inherit `QGraphicsItem` but then I  get errors about virtual functions that I don't know how to define (like `boundingRect` which would depend on the item contents... could be objects, images, svg, text... for some i know how to get the bounding rectangle but for others really idk)... Is that the only way to do this ?

How can I identify he items at the location of the mouse position, and what is preventing me to change the `x` and `y` for the item once mouse is moved ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to implement everything yourself, you shouldn't be using `QGraphicsView` at all. If you wish to use `QGraphicsView`, there's no need to reimplement any of its virtual methods. Just use it as-is, and set the item's `QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable` flag.

A complete example is provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11235761/1329652). The only reason for reimplementation of `QGraphicsView::mousePressEvent` was to implement creation of new items.

Comment: I have been struggling to inherit from QGraphicsItem because I get errors about "can't allocate an object of abstract type Item" - so i end up having to define boundingRect and a number of other things I have no clue about how to define or how to call

Comment: @Thalia The documentation tells you what these methods should do. You don't call them, the scene and the view does. If you have any definite questions, ask them separately. Feel free to look at the example code I've posted in the linked answer, and in [a multitude of other answers I have on QGraphicsViews](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1329652+QGraphicsView).

Comment: Defining the boundingRect means I have to define the bounding rectangle for all objects - and for some, like text and svg, I don't know how... with polygon I am still fighting

Comment: I already had a "paint" but the QGraphicsItem version requires a QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option that I don't know where to get from

Comment: Sorry what do you mean ? about not deriving but using as is ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I just wrote you should instantiate an abstract class - I should go to sleep...

Comment: @Thalia I think you approach it the wrong way. `QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option` is a parameter that is passed *to you*. You don't have to worry about it if your item is not styled. As for finding the bounding rectangle, it should be easy as well for anything you can think of. Just check in Qt's documentation for relevant methods.  For example, `QFontMetricsF::boundingRect` .

Comment: I will have to read more about this to understand how to set it up... thank you for the examples, i will be back

Comment: how does a single item look like? has text? polygon? both? more?

Comment: I have managed to inherit from QGraphicsItem and my paint and anything else works. Mouse press gives me qDebug info about the item and mouse location, I get qDebug info in MouseRelease event - but the item does not move... I guess I sill must work on it

Comment: @Thalia You don't need to process mouse events yourself. Did you declare the item movable? If you implement the mouse events, are you invoking the implementation of the base class? Otherwise it wont' work. Most likely, you need to remove your mouse event implementations, and it will just start to work. Your implementations are likely unnecessary anyway.