# Draggable QGraphicsRectItem with mouse on PyQt6

Tags: pyqt6

I have a simple question..

I have a `QGraphicsRectItem()` on a PlotWidget; is there any pre-built way to drag it around with the mouse and drop it on another position? I'm thinking of something like an idk.. a `setDraggable()` attribute or the equivalent or do i have to build that method from scratch using mouse events?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Moving an item with the mouse on QGraphicsView / QGraphicsScene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28905460/moving-an-item-with-the-mouse-on-qgraphicsview-qgraphicsscene)

Comment: `item.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.GraphicsItemFlag.ItemIsMovable)`. See the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicsitem.html#GraphicsItemFlag-enum).